# Remove Volume Group from a re-pourpsed disk

Tags: linux, lvm

I have this SSD that was in another Ovirt cluster that I destroyed, and now I'm trying to re-purpose this disk but can't seem to clear it. I have tried `wipefs` and `dd` but it still shows up in `fdisk -l`. How can I clear all lvms from this disk?

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 3.5 TiB, 3840755982336 bytes, 7501476528 sectors
Disk model: SAMSUNG MZ7LH3T8
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 58.25 GiB, 62537072640 bytes, 122142720 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 61C206C7-69A3-4C51-9215-1C0B45E32661

Device           Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1    2048    788479    786432  384M Linux filesystem
/dev/mmcblk0p2  788480   1048575    260096  127M EFI System
/dev/mmcblk0p3 1048576   1050623      2048    1M BIOS boot
/dev/mmcblk0p4 1050624 122142686 121092063 57.8G Linux filesystem

[core@h2-master-01 ~]$ sudo lsblk
NAME                                                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                        8:0    0  3.5T  0 disk
ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc_tmeta   253:0    0 15.8G  0 lvm
â ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc-tpool 253:2    0  3.5T  0 lvm
â   ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc     253:3    0  3.5T  1 lvm
â   ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_lv_data                     253:4    0  3.4T  0 lvm
ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc_tdata   253:1    0  3.5T  0 lvm
  ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc-tpool 253:2    0  3.5T  0 lvm
    ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_thinpool_gluster_vg_sdc     253:3    0  3.5T  1 lvm
    ââgluster_vg_sdc-gluster_lv_data                     253:4    0  3.4T  0 lvm
mmcblk0                                                  179:0    0 58.2G  0 disk
ââmmcblk0p1                                              179:1    0  384M  0 part /boot
ââmmcblk0p2                                              179:2    0  127M  0 part /boot/efi
ââmmcblk0p3                                              179:3    0    1M  0 part
ââmmcblk0p4                                              179:4    0 57.8G  0 part /sysroot
mmcblk0boot0                                             179:8    0    4M  1 disk
mmcblk0boot1                                             179:16   0    4M  1 disk

[core@h2-master-01 ~]$ sudo lvdisplay
[core@h2-master-01 ~]$ sudo vgdisplay
[core@h2-master-01 ~]$ sudo pvdisplay
```

Comment: Have you try to create PV with `pvcreate -f /dev/sda` or even  `pvcreate -ff /dev/sda` and then continue with VG, LV creation

Comment: returns this: Can't open /dev/sda exclusively.  Mounted filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

`wipefs -a /dev/sda` with a reboot seemed looks to have cleared the disk. Thanks all!